# How to run ./configure from a different folder?

Tags: bash, configuration

I'm writing an ansible playbook which is supposed to compile from source some tool and install it.

While checking my playbook, I've tried running the relevant commands manually to check their output.

So, In my ansible play book I've configured this:

```
- name: Configure kafkacat
      command: . {{ install_dest }}/configure arg1
        args:
          enable_json: "--enable-json"
      sudo: yes
```

But before running the playbook, I ran manually:
`. /tmp/kafkacat/configure --enable-json` which is supposed to be equivalent to running `./configure` in the current directory, but the command fails and I get an error.

So how can it be done?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a lot of cases, depending on the software configure relies on having includes and headers opened from the current working directory.

ansible does support a "chdir" argument. Maybe that is the solution that will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think they are equivalent. 
The dot without following space replaces the path to your current *directory*, whereas a dot preceding a space makes commands of a script run in your current *shell*.
There is a good explanation here :
https://askubuntu.com/q/232932